# ¿Como obtengo los valores de unos checkBox seleccionados en un checkedListBox y guardarlos en una lista?

Tags: vb.net

Como puedo los valores de unos checkbox seleccionados en un checkedlistbox y poder guardar esos valores en una lista para poder iterarlos en otro metodo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que estoy usando en el boton es para capturar los datos de los 2 checkbox que seleccione pero siempre me selecciona el segundo checkbox seleccionado y no puedo obtener el valor del otro.

```
 Private Sub BtnBuscarArchivo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBuscarArchivo.Click
  If ChkTiendas.CheckedItems.Count <> 0 Then

  For Each itemIndex In ChkTiendas.CheckedIndices
      Dim selectedItem As String = ChkTiendas.SelectedValue.ToString()
      valoresSeleccionados.Add(selectedItem)
  Next

 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Mira tu codigo.. si estas haciendo un for, estas iterando para ir de uno en uno, y dentro del for, como usas ese indice???? ;) ahi esta la clave...para algo lo obtenes ;)

Answer (score 0):

CheckedListBox.CheckedItems es ya una colección de items marcados (checked) solo tienes que iterar sobre esa colección, si la necesitas en un arreglo usa la propiedad copyTo:

CopyTo(Array, Int32)
Copies the entire collection into an existing array at a specified location within the array.
Espero esto te ayude